# Not getting exact form of output using terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    int n;

    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        cin>>n;
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }
}
```

Input test file:

```
2
1
2
```

Now when I copy this input and paste it into terminal, it gives the output as follows:

```
2
1
21

2

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.485 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

But I want the output to be in following format as is given in IDE like codeblocks.

```
2
1
1
2
2
```

Is it possible to display output in this format when copying the input to the terminal?

Comment: The code you've posted produces the correct output in the terminal for me...

Comment: For me,it's not working. You can see my output. 1 comes just after 2 and it looks like 21

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces the correct input you want for me. Your issue is most likely that you *paste* the input into the terminal and so it all appears immediately. If instead you input your input with the keyboard manually, **one by one**, it should produce your desired view.

Although I don't know why you would want to do this as some lines of your terminal "output" are not the output but instead the input due to race conditions.

```
2 // Input (stdin)
1 // Input (stdin)
1 // Output (stdout)
2 // Input (stdin)
2 // Output (stdout)
```

---

**Edit:** In response to the comment to this answer

> I want the stdout to have 2 1 1 2 2 after I paste the the input and press enter.

To accomplish that you need to understand the difference between `stdin` and `stdout` whilst both print to the terminal when you are running applications they are separate streams. `stdin` typically reads from the keyboard, this is different to `stdout` which typically prints to the terminal output window.

The below simple program separates the input and output into 2 separate `for` loops so that you can see the difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, n, i;
    vector<int> numbers;

    cin >> t;

    // Input
    for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        cin >> n;
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }

    // Output
    cout << t << endl;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << "\n" << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

When you run this program you will see

```
$ ./a.out
2
1
2
2
1
1
2
2
```

In this "output" the first 3 numbers are from `stdin` whilst the last 5 are from `stdout` and produce the correct output that you require.

```
$ ./a.out
2 // Input (stdin)
1 // Input (stdin)
2 // Input (stdin)
2 // Output (stdout)
1 // Output (stdout)
1 // Output (stdout)
2 // Output (stdout)
2 // Output (stdout)
```

Comment: I know it will produce a correct output if I paste the output one by one.  But that is not what I want. During competitive coding, I do need to paste the whole input in one go.

Comment: @shivammitra This question is very unclear and becoming more unclear. Do you want `stdout` to have `2 1 1 2 2` or do you want that output to be displayed over `stdin` and `stdout` as I've shown in the answer? I think you need to read up on the differences between `stdin` and `stdout` and how they are represented in the terminal.

Comment: Even after pasting the input, the input/output on terminal should look like 2 1 1  2 2 where where some are inputs and some are outputs. Copying and pasting in codeblocks in windows does give the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a race condition between your input feedback and your program's output.

Preventing your terminal from displaying all you type in when you copy and paste your input isn't possible in a portable way.

You could always get reliable results if you delayed your program's output until you're sure there's no input left. But you can't have it the other way around unless you yourself humanly and patiently wait for the previous line of output before typing your next.  But you're not going to be able to achieve that with most terminals' copy-and-paste facility.

Comment: That means it is not possible to achieve such such an output. So, the only way is to write the input one by one.